# How to read any NFC binary message with Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, nfc, windows-phone-8, proximity

I am developing an NFC app for Windows Phone and I want to subscribe to **any** binary message. How can I achieve a functionality like `nfc.SubscribeForAnyMessage( HandleNFCMessage);` ? Currently I can only subscribe to a specific message type such as `nfc.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", HandleNFCMessage);`

Thanks,

Can.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the MessageType as the only method to subscribe for message is the method you already mentioned. To see what MessageTypes can be specified see the documentation of the PublishBinaryMessage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701129.aspx

Perhaps if you specify "Windows" as MessageType you will get all binary messages but I can't test that right now. You can always subscribe your app to multiple MessageTypes.

Comment: when I change "NDEF" to "Windows", I get an argument exception at the `SubscribeForMessage` method telling that value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: I just tested it myself and I get the same error message. I've looked in some previous test-documentation and couldn't find a case where I successfully have managed to use "Windows" as MessageType.

Answer (score 0):

What'a a "Binary NFC" message? All messages handled within the WP8/Win8 proxmity framework must have a message type. "Binary messages" in this context are just messages that have a byte array (IBuffer) payload but still have a message type.

I don't believe it's possible to subscribe to a wildcard of NFC messages. You can definitely signup to [some basic types of MessageTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701129.aspx) (like NDEF, etc) but every app can declare their own custom message type like Windows.MyApp.MyMessage that won't be caught by a wildcard.

What exactly are you trying to do? If you're just trying to know when an NFC tag is available to write over it consider using [DeviceArrived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.devicearrived.aspx) and [DeviceDeparted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.devicedeparted.aspx) events.

Comment: I am experimenting with an app that will read and save ANY kind of NFC tag. if the tag is in a known format, it will display it (e.g. URI), if the payload is of an unknown type, it will store it as a byte array

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 supports only "NDEF" formatted tags.
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Use_NFC_tags_with_Windows_Phone_8